# String out of index

Tags: python, string, indexing

**My requirements**

Use Python to create a function `cleanstring(S)` to "clean up" the spaces in a sentence `S`.

- The sentence may have extra spaces at the front and/or at the end and/or between words.
- The subroutine returns a new version of the sentence without the extra spaces.

  - That is, in the new string, the words should be the same but there should be no spaces at the start, only one space between each word and no spaces at the end.

This program is about you writing code to search through a string to find words and so you are not allowed to use the split function in Python.

You can solve this problem with the basic capabilities of the if and while statements and string operations of len and concatentation.

For example: if the input is: " Hello to the world !" then the output should be: "Hello to the world!"

**Question**

My program creates an error.

How do I fix the error in my program?

```
def cleanupstring (S):
newstring = ["", 0]
j = 1
for i in range(len(S)):
    if S[i] != " " and S[i+1] != " ":
        newstring[0] = newstring[0] + S[i]
    else:
        newstring[1] = newstring [1] + 1

return newstring


# main program

sentence = input("Enter a string: ")

outputList = cleanupstring(sentence)

print("A total of", outputList[1], "characters have been removed from your 
string.")
print("The new string is:", outputList[0])
```

Comment: try regex for your problem

Comment: Try `for i in range(len(S) -1):`. In `and S[i+1] != " ":` you're attempting to access the `i+1` index... Well when you get to the very end of that loop, `i+1` overshoots the end of the list.

Comment: On the last character there is no `S[i+1]`.

Comment: If you are going to ask about the error your program produces it is always a good idea to share the error and traceback with us. We can't look over your shoulder and see your screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different methods can be used for removing leading and trailing spaces, for converting multiple spaces to one and to remove spaces before exclamation mark, comma etc:

```
mystr = "  Hello  .       To  ,   the world !  "
print(mystr)

mystr = mystr.strip()               # remove leading and trailing spaces

import re                           # regex module
mystr = re.sub(r'\s+'," ", mystr)   # convert multiple spaces to one space.
mystr = re.sub(r'\s*([,.!])',"\\1", mystr)  # remove spaces before comma, period and exclamation etc.
print(mystr)
```

Output:

```
  Hello  .       To  ,   the world !  
Hello. To, the world!
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions in comment are correct. You are getting an erro because you try to access **S[i+1]** in loop **for i in range(len(S)):**

**Solution**

Loop only till second-last element

```
for i in range(len(S) - 1):
```

**Suggestion**

As you said you can't use **spit()** function, so assuming that you can use other functions (to modify string, not to extract words), **strip()** function and a little bit of regular expressions will do what your **cleanupstring()** is trying to do.

**Code**

```
def cleanupstring (S):
    newstring = ["", 0]
    init_length = len(S)
    S = S.strip()    #remove space from front and end
    S = re.sub(r'\s+'," ", S)   #remove extra space from between words
    newstring[0] = S
    newstring[1] = init_length - len(S)
    return newstring

# main program
sentence = input("Enter a string: ")
outputList = cleanupstring(sentence)

print("A total of", outputList[1], "characters have been removed from your 
string.")
print("The new string is:", outputList[0])
```